# How do I delete specific documents from a FirebaseTS Database with Angular 13?

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Hello I am fairly new to the Angular framework so bear with me please. I have a feed/timeline made out of simple posts that contain text. That text is saved in Firebase. This is how it gets saved:

```
firestore = new FirebaseTSFirestore();

createItem(postInput: HTMLInputElement) {
    let postMessage = postInput.value;
    let postId = this.firestore.genDocId();

    this.firestore.create(
      {
        path: ["Posts", postId],
        data: {
          postMessage: postMessage,
          timestamp: FirebaseTSApp.getFirestoreTimestamp()
        }
      }
    )
  }
```

The names of documents inside the Posts folder are randomly generated through `let postId = this.firestore.genDocId();`. Each document is a post in my timeline.
Then I have a "trash bin" icon in my post html component, which I plan on using as a delete button.

```
<span><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></span>
```

This is how the list looks like:
[timeline](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QV3T1.png)

What I need is a way to delete the document to which that trash icon belongs to. I have searched the internet but have found little. How do I do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to add a function click and add the element Id with your icon as:

   <i class="fa fa-trash" (click) = removeItem(id)” >
2. Then in your TS component you can:

   removeItem(id:any) {
   this.firestore.db.collection(‘collection name’).doc(id).delete()

Comment: thanks, what is the `db` part in the removeItem function?

Comment: Referring to your code. It will be this.firestore.delete(id)

Comment: So this is what I have so far:

`firestore = new FirebaseTSFirestore();
  postId: any;

  removeItem(postId: any) {
    let db = this.firestore.delete(postId);
    
    this.firestore.db.collection('Posts').doc(postId).delete(postId);
  }`
It tells me that "Property 'db' does not exist on type 'FirebaseTSFirestore'". Sorry if it's a dumb question but what am I doing wrong?

Comment: i see that your code is using this.firestore.create() function. you can delete your post using the following code:
   
 this.firestore.delete(
      {
        path: ["Posts", postId],
      }
    )


Let me know if that works.

Comment: I've actually tried it this way and it doesn't work, but I think the problem might be in the postId parameter for the removeItem function. The postId variable from the html component gives an error (Property 'postId' does not exist on type 'PostComponent') if I do not declare it outside the removeItem function. Might this be the problem?